# Finding the minimum number of steps to achieve a certain error

Tags: calculus

I have the function $f(x) = \ln(x)$. Suppose $|x-e| < 1 $ then what is the minimum number of steps (from the taylor series) needed to achieve an error of $0.5 \cdot 10^{-1}$?

So I know the error term is written as $R_{n+1}(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-e)^{n+1}$

So $-1+e < x < 1+e$. I'll let $x= -1+e$ to get $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(-1)^{n+1}$. How am I suppose to determined for what $n$ allows the inequality to be satisifed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bound the derivative.  The first derivative of $\log x$ is $\frac 1x$, which in your interval has a maximum value of $\frac 1{e-1}\approx 0.58$, while your target is $0.05$ so you need more terms.  The second derivative is $\frac 1{x^2}$, so you find the maximum value of $\frac 1{2!x^2}$ over your interval, which is $\frac 1{2(e-1)^2} \approx 0.17$, still too large.  Keep going until it gets small enough.  If the $n^{\text{th}}$ term is smaller than $0.05$ you need the Taylor series through $x^{n-1}$